# Angular 2 passing values from selector to html template

Tags: angular

I want to pass simple values from my selector (such as class and id) to the template. I've imported my `component` into a `module` and placed the imported `selector` in the html of the importing `component` I want to pass values to the html/component being imported. Below is how I'm using the selector and the html template of the component being imported.

`<my-graph graphid="my-graph-1" graphclasses="graph"></my-graph>`

`<svg id="{{graphid}}" class="{{graphclasses}}" width="90" height="90"></svg>`

The graphid is also used in the graph's `component.ts` file

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either @Output() and pass the shared data from graph component into your component that is holding both the graph component and the svg. Or, use a sharedService -- inject the service into both the graph component and attach the ID to sharedService, and then also use the same service in the parent component to assign the ID to svg ID.

Similar to having a store, and having the store hold all your data.